# Custom Data Type with Numpy Load Data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following data:

```
1:-1 2:-1 3:0.213213 ...
1:0.905906 2:-1 4:-1 ...
```

Where the data is formatted as such, `[index]:[value]`, and that the value is to be imported in such a way that each line represents an array. So I am expecting a 2D array like the following:

```
array = ([[-1, -1, 0.213213, ...]
         [0.905906, -1, NaN, -1, ...] 
        ])
```

Using `numpy.loadtxt` (if it is possible), how would I go about doing that? I have read the documentation for `dtype`, but I just can't seemed to import the data where the key correspond to the array's index, and its corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

I used `read_csv` from pandas although np.loadtxt works too I believe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file', header=None, sep=' |:')
df_new = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, 
                      columns=range(np.max(df.iloc[:, -2]))) # create empty dataframe

# Iterate over rows and place values at correct position.
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    idx = row[0::2].astype('int').values-1
    vals = row[1::2].values
    df_new.iloc[index, idx] = vals

df_new.values
```

Returns:

```
array([[-1.0, -1.0, 0.213213, nan],
       [0.905906, -1.0, nan, -1.0]], dtype=object)
```